# Absolute Value Inequality - Precision

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

So I was writing a computer program, which is supposed to check whether $x$, an approximation of $\sqrt{a}$, is close enough to $\sqrt{x}$. Since these definitions aren't very precise, I defined "close enough" as $$\left|a - x^2\right| \le \dfrac{1}{10^{100}}$$
However my code involves division. Since doubles/floats do not give the desired precision, I had to use the BigDecimal class which requires the programmer to specify the decimal place to which it should round the answer. Originally, I put 100. This worked for my original case of $a = 2$. However, I realized that simply running the code once would not work. Running the code more than once wouldn't work either, because Java would optimize producing inaccurate results. I decided to run the code for all $1 \le a \le 100$. $100$ didn't work for 5, however, so I put 101. This worked for more values of $a$, but then stopped working. I had no idea how to choose the right value of $n$ at which to round to, which is why I am posing the question here.

---

Find the least positive integer $n$ such that the statement

"For all real numbers $x$, if $\left|\sqrt{a}-x\right| \le \dfrac{1}{10^n}$, then $\left|a - x^2\right| \le \dfrac{1}{10^{100}}$"

holds true for all integers $1 \le a \le 100$

---

Comment: You'll want to look at $|a^2 - x|$ in your entire post, or label $x$ the approximation of $\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, including the little correction:
$$\begin{align*}
|\sqrt x - a| & \leq 10^{-n} \\
\Leftrightarrow |\sqrt x - a||\sqrt x + a| & \leq 10^{-n} |\sqrt x + a| \\
\Leftrightarrow |x - a^2| & \leq 10^{-n} |\sqrt x + a|
\end{align*}$$
This gives us
$$10^{-n} |\sqrt x + a| \leq 10^{-100}$$
Which depends on the number whose square root you want to approximate.
If you take $a = \sqrt x$ (the "ideal"), you'd need
$$n \approx 100 -\log_{10} (\frac1{2\sqrt x}) = 100 + \log_{10}(2) + \frac12 \log_{10} x$$

Comment: Well I want to approximate $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, all the way up to $\sqrt{97}$ (or all square-free integers from $1$ to $100$)

Comment: Then use $x = 100$ in the approximation (to stay conservative).
This would give $n \approx 100 + \log_{10} 2 + 1 < 102$. The problem is that this doesn't take rounding errors into account, so you can probably double that to be sure.